# Long text is cropped in Graphics

Tags: graphics, text

I want to convert a text slogan into graphic, and then add to an image. However, the long text is cropped. How to fix?

Here is the code:

```
slogan[text1_, text2_] := Block[{s1, s2},
  s1 = Graphics[{Text[
      Style[text1, FontSize -> 30, Bold, Black, Background -> None, 
       FontFamily -> "SeasideResortNF"]]}];
  s2 = Graphics[{Text[
      Style[text2, FontSize -> 25, Bold, Black, Background -> None, 
       FontFamily -> "Alex Brush"]]}];
  ImageCompose[s1, s2, Scaled[{.5, 0.35}]]
  ]
```

And for the long text input:

```
slogan["'This long text is cropped'", "Why?"]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: windows 10, Mathematica 11.0.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the font. But not the problem, can you just try a very long text"? And it is cropped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default graphic width of 360 pixels is being exceeded.  Find out how big your text is and fit the graphic accordingly, e.g.

```
slogan[text1_, text2_] := Block[{s1, s2},

  maxwidth = Max[360,
    First@ImageDimensions@Rasterize@
       Text[Style[text1, FontSize -> 30, Bold, Black,
         Background -> None, FontFamily -> "Broadway"]],
    First@ImageDimensions@Rasterize@
       Text[Style[text2, FontSize -> 25, Bold, Black,
         Background -> None, FontFamily -> "Script MT Bold"]]];

  s1 = Graphics[{Text[
      Style[text1, FontSize -> 30, Bold, Black, Background -> None, 
       FontFamily -> "Broadway"]]}, ImageSize -> maxwidth]; 
  s2 = Graphics[{Text[
      Style[text2, FontSize -> 25, Bold, Black, Background -> None, 
       FontFamily -> "Script MT Bold"]]}, ImageSize -> maxwidth]; 
  ImageCompose[s1, s2, Scaled[{.5, 0.35}]]]

slogan["'This long text is cropped'", "Why?"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1! Exactly! Thank you for your help! Vote up!